# Recursive factorial error return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, recursion

I try to write a factorial using recursive function. What is wrong with this code?
I get error return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]

```
#include <iostream.h>

int factorial(int);

int factorial(int number)
{
    return number==0?1: number * factorial*(number - 1);
}

void main(void)
{
    int number;

    cout << "Please enter a natural number: ";
    cin >> number;
    if (number < 1)
        cout << "That is not a natural number.\n";
    else
        cout << number << " factorial is: " << factorial(number) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `factorial*(..)` .. surely that's not desired.

Comment: Nor is `<iostream.h>` for a compiler that's less than a dozen years old.

Comment: `main` returns `int`, *not* `void`. If a book or instructor told you to use `void main(void)`, find a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix the code.
main must be int and function argument should be entered immediately without `*` in between:

```
#include <iostream.h>

int factorial(int number)
{
    return number==0?1: number * factorial(number - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int number;

    cout << "Please enter a natural number: ";
    cin >> number;
    if (number < 1)
        cout << "That is not a natural number.\n";
    else
        cout << number << " factorial is: " << factorial(number) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `main` should return `int`, not `void`. Also `void` within parenthesis is useless in C++.

Use:

```
int main() {
```

or:

```
auto main() -> int {
```